# I will ring you in the evening

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to use the verb "ring" instead of "call" even if I am using a mobile phone?

As far as I am aware, "ring" can be used in that sense and was widely spread with dial phones.

Comment: It is acceptable to use. However, it is more commonly used in British English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is still acceptable to say you will 'ring' or you will 'call', even if both you and the person you are phoning have mobile phones.  However, the use of 'ring' is becoming less common than it used to be.